# How to calculate number of leap years between two years in C#

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, date

Is there a better way to calculate number of leap years between two years.  Assuming I have start date and end date.

I have my code, but I think there should be more elegant way.

calling code:

```
var numberOfLeapYears = NumberOfLeapYears(startDate.Year + 1, endDate.Year - 1);
```

function itself:

```
    private static int NumberOfLeapYears(int startYear, int endYear)
    {
        var counter = 0;

        for (var year = startYear; year <= endYear; year++)
            counter += DateTime.IsLeapYear(year) ? 1 : 0;

        return counter;
    }
```

So if I have `startDate = "10/16/2006"` and `endDate = "4/18/2004"` I should only have 1 leap year (2000) in result.  Another words startDate's Year and endDate's year should not be calculated, only years in between.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable implementation

Comment: I assume you meant 10/16/1996. In this case, you don't care about the 2/29/2004, which was a leap day that occurred prior to the end date of 4/18/2004?

Comment: Do you need to take into account that the leap year calculations were different before the Gregorian calendar reform? Also, do you need to take into account that some countries adopted the reformed calendar at different times? The number of leap years between two dates *in England* can be different than the number of leap years between two dates *in the US* for example.

Comment: @Eric Lippert.  No I don't need to take into account leap years different before Gregorian calendar reform.  I don't need to take into account any countris (US only).  Thanks Eric.

Comment: If you think of the number of loops, you can accelerate the process starting jumping by 4 years once you find the first one.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can count it using analytic approach. A year is a leap year if it can be divided by 4, but can't be divided by 100, except of case when it can be divided by 400. Assuming that you can count such number by following code:

```
static int LeapYearsBetween(int start, int end)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(start < end);
    return LeapYearsBefore(end) - LeapYearsBefore(start + 1);
}

static int LeapYearsBefore(int year)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(year > 0);
    year--;
    return (year / 4) - (year / 100) + (year / 400);
}
```

Some kind of math magic. It is much effective solution than using LINQ.

Comment: I like this approach since there is no iteration for each year.  In the begging I like more LINQ approach, but after analyzing your code I found it should not have impact on performance since LINQ approach need to go through each year and find if it is leap or not.  Yours solution just pure math.  I tested and it gives the same result as LINQ.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Vlad Bezden, currently all the years are bellow 10000, so there is no feasible performance issue and because it will be done in memory it's not bad in all, in this cases I personally prefer clean code, if it was for database read write, yes it would be better to do it better.

Comment: Personally, I'd try to stick to O(1) algorithms over O(n) wherever possible.

Comment: FYI: Last method is the same as "(year-1) * 0.2425" if using doubles. :)

Comment: This is pretty fantastic! Thanks so much for sharing.

Answer (score 12):

You can do it with LINQ simply as bellow:

```
var leepYears = Enumerable.Range(startYear, endYear - startYear + 1)
                              .Count(x => DateTime.IsLeapYear(x));
```

Comment: @Vlad Bezden LINQ is great tool, but for this task there is much efficient solution (see my answer). When range is large LINQ solution is slow, but my algorithm is independent from range size.

Comment: +1 I really this code - it's easy to read and the intent of code is very clear.

Comment: @Saeed yes I like how code is clean, but agree with mace that LINQ solution is slower especially when we have big difference between startYear and endYear.

Comment: @Vlad Bezden, but in most cases you have no big difference in start year and end year biggest possible is 2000 which is not big in this days.

Answer (score 3):

This should perform much better for large spans of time:

```
public int LeapYearsBetween(int year1, int year2)
{
    var y1 = new DateTime(year1, 1, 1);
    var y2 = new DateTime(year2, 1, 1);
    var nonLeapDays = 365 * (y2.Year - y1.Year);
    var leapDays = (y2 - y1).Days - nonLeapDays;
    return leapDays;
}
```

Note that this counts the earlier year if it is a leap year, but not the later year.  You'll need to modify the function if you need different behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Another Linq :-)

```
int start = 1980;
int end = 2000;
var count = Enumerable.Range(start, end - start + 1)
                      .Aggregate(0, (a, b) => DateTime.IsLeapYear(b) ? a + 1 : a);
```

Comment: Actually I like mace's solution, since it is pure calculation and no iteration, so I think mace's solution has less CPU utilization.  I have more than 100K records to calculate Leap Years.

Answer (score 2):

Just another code with primitives types

```
    public static int CountLeapYears(int startYear, int endYear) 
    {
        int acc = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            if ((startYear % 4 == 0 && startYear % 100 != 0) || startYear % 400 == 0)
                acc++;
            if (startYear + 1 == endYear) break;
            startYear++;
        }

        return acc;
    }
```