# How to round numbers in range after division (10.25 to 11)?

Tags: c++, floating-point, rounding

For a school project I need to calculate the leap years. The problem is, I need to round the int.

For example someone is born in 1961.

```
double yearsbetween; yearsbetween = birthyear - 1918;

double leapyears; leapyears = ( yearsbetween / 4 );
```

If `birthyear = 1961` I get `leapyears = 10.75` but that is wrong.. I need to be 11.

If an answer is 10.25 it need to be rounded to 10. If an answer is 10.75 it need to be rounded to 11.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Can you show how you are calculating the leap years?  You shouldn't need to round at all.

Comment: Why would you use floating point numbers when dealing with integer values such as years?

Comment: 11/4 is actually 2.75, not 10.75. I think you meant (1961-1918)/4=10.75. Programming requires you to be precise, just like math !

Comment: I don't think you can use an arithmetic formula to determine the number of leap years. I think you will need to iterate from the first year to the last and count leap years.

Comment: `std::ceil` will do it for you.

Comment: Sure. For example someone is born in 1961. The year I calculate is from is 1918. So I do 1961-1918. Then I get 43 years. Then I do 43/4 and I get 10 (if I use double I get 10.75). But the real answer is 11 leapyears .. and not 10.

Comment: @HelloWorld: Perhaps. But Nien hasn't posted any code, so we can't tell.

Comment: You are probably doing integer math somewhere in your calculation.

Comment: @MSalters sure.

Comment: Where is the OP?

Comment: I added some. I hope you understand now. I'm all new to this, sorry if its not clear for you.

Comment: Include something (code) you tried so far, so that someone will help you.

Comment: C# code but should work for you (no rounding required): https://stackoverflow.com/a/4587611/4342498

Comment: "How to round numbers" - [std::round](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) and friends are a good start. See also [std::floor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/floor) and [std::ceil](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ceil).

Comment: A small nit... When you have a range like `[a, b]`, the number of elements in the range is `b - a + 1` (not `b - a`). You can easily verify it with `[0,3]`, which has elements `{0,1,2,3}`. It may explain why you are off. You calculation may be off by one here: `birthyear - 1918`, which results in being off by `0.25` here: `leapyears = ( yearsbetween / 4 );`. You should probably ask your teacher for more test cases to cover edge cases, like a centurion/100 year old person born in 1900 and dies in 1999, 2000 or 2001.

Answer (score 2):

you have to specifically look at each year to check for leap years. your assumption of every 4th year as leap is wrong, as there are some exceptions:

it is not a leap year, if it is divisible by 100 and not divisible by 400

examples:

- 1900 is not a leap year
- 2000 is a leap year

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we are working only in a period in which the leap years are those years, and only those years, that are divisible by four.

Given a number *n*, the number of positive numbers less than or equal to *n* that are multiples of four is floor(*n*/4). Let L(*n*) be this value, floor(*n*/4).

If we take a number *m*, the number of positive multiples of four up to *m* is L(*m*). When we subtract L(*n*), the result, L(*m*)−L(*n*), is the number of multiples of four greater than *n* but less than or equal to *m*.

Therefore, the number of leap years between year 1918 and year *m* is floor(*m*/4) − floor(1918/4) = floor(*m*/4) − 479. (If the base year were a leap year and we wanted to include it inside the period instead of outside, we could replace L(*n*) with L(*n*−1).

The above is easily extendable to the larger leap year pattern. By changing L(*n*) to floor(*n*/4) − floor(*n*/100) + floor(*n*/400), it becomes a count of positive numbers up to *n* that are multiples of four but are not multiples of 100 unless they are multiples of 400. Then L(*m*) − L(*n*) is the number of leap rules between *n* and *m*.

Thus a proper formula for the period covered by this rule is floor(*n*/4) − floor(*n*/100) + floor(*n*/400) − 464. Using C’s integer arithmetic, this is easily evaluated as `n/4 - n/100 + n/400 - 464`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you need is [`std::ceil`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ceil)

You also have in the `std::ceil` reference a link to other rounding functions, I recommend 
going through those also.

Comment: While this answers the literal question it doesn't point out that the OP's formula is flawed and will add extra leap years for certain date ranges.

Comment: That is true, I did only answer the literal question. My bad there.

Answer (score 0):

So this isn't relevant until [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) and I even had to [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52393148/how-is-a-chronoyear-object-constructed?noredirect=1&lq=1) to figure out how to use [`chrono::year`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year). But the best solution for this, if available, would be something like:

```
const chrono::year birthyear{ 1961 };
auto leapyears = 0;

for(chrono::year i{ 1918 }; i <= birthyear; ++i) {
    if(i.is_leap()) {
        ++leapyears;
    }
}
```

I've linked a [live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Mh9k7lUztUJuXawb) by forking [@HowardHinnant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576911/howard-hinnant)'s example from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52393402/2642059).