# How is a chrono::year Object Constructed?

Tags: c++, date, time, epoch, c++-chrono

I just noticed that [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) is going to have [`chrono::year`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year). It's constructor takes in an `int` in the range: *[-32767, 32767]*, however I am unclear what this argument represents.

- Would this be consistent with [`tm_year`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm)'s 1900 origin?
- Or perhaps [`time_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time_t)'s 1970 origin?
- Or perhaps it's in [Anno Domini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anno_Domini) with a 0 origin?

**EDIT:**
This is key to the understanding of what is meant by the [`is_leap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year/is_leap) function `chrono::year` offers. Without an origin it's unclear what year is represented here.

Comment: The standard is maddeningly unhelpful: *year represents a year in the civil calendar* https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/time.cal.year#overview-1

Comment: Since it's Gregorian time, I'd assume 0 is 0, but that's just an assumption. Fortunately there's still another couple years to get the wording sorted out in the Standard.

Comment: What's unclear about cppreference's description? "The class year represents a year in the [proleptic Gregorian calendar](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar). Its range is [-32767, 32767]."?

Comment: @JesperJuhl does the Proleptic Gregorian calendar have an origin?

Comment: @user4581301 I was actually going to try to find a compiler which had already implemented C++2A and see if I couldn't use this.

Comment: @Jonathan Mee - see the link.

Comment: The calendar's origin is "year zero" which technically didn't exist. The first year of the Gregorian calendar (then [Julian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar)) was year 1.

Comment: Standard link says nothing about Gregorian, just Civil Calendar, of which Gregorian is merely the elephant in the room. This is interesting wording.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I... don't see anything about an origin in that article... though 1582 is thrown around a good deal. Is that supposed to be the origin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In 25.8.1 [time.cal.general]:

> The types in 25.8 describe the civil (Gregorian) calendar and its relationship to `sys_days` and `local_days`.

The wording on this was (is) challenging as the intent is to model the Gregorian calendar (as does C++ currently via the C API) without offending those who follow other calendars.

I also am just now noting that the word ["proleptic"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar) is missing from the spec, and should probably be added in a strategic spot.

To directly answer the question, the integral associated with `std::chrono::year` is the Anno Domini reference, as defined by Pope Gregory in 1582, but running both backwards and forwards in time.  As I write this, the year is `2018y`.

And (answering Jonathan Mee's comment below), this program:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    const auto foo = 2018y;
    cout << int{foo} << '\n';
}
```

Outputs:

```
2018
```

[Live demo that you can experiment with](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UzvJyjoeg79iC7Yu) with the proviso that the ["date.h"](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) example implementation puts things in `namespace date` instead of `namespace std::chrono`.

I should also note that this software allows for *user-written* calendars to interoperate with the `std::chrono` system.  Here is an example of the [Julian calendar](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/julian.html).  There are a couple more examples [here](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).

---

Finally, a brief note on the rationale as to why the current year is represented as `year{2018}` (Anno Domini), as opposed to `year{48}` (`time_t`'s 1970 origin), or `year{118}` (`tm_year`'s 1900 origin):

[This philosophy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y0X0ZYbnHxA) is hysterical when used in movies.  But gets tiresome when used in software design.  This library tries to do the expected.

Comment: OK, so if I do `const auto foo = 2018y` Then what will this output? `cout << static_cast<int>(foo)` Is it 2018, indicating the origin is at 0? Or is it 436, indicating the origin is at 1582?

Comment: I missed the `#include "date.h"` on my first reading of the example and couldn't figure out how this could possibly work in C++17. Anyway, on second pass, thank you so much for pasting all that in!

Comment: You're welcome.  But the date.h was already pasted in as a "live demo" from the project website.  I just modified a copy for this question.  The example implementation will work (with varying degrees of success) back to C++11 on clang, gcc, and VS.

Comment: I had a follow up question, but I realized I was cheating on the scope of this question. If you have some insight could you help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52394623/2642059