# How can I Populate a chrono::year With the Current Year?

Tags: c++, date, epoch, c++-chrono, c++20

So I understand from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52393148/2642059) that the integer used in the construction of a [`chrono::year`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year) corresponds to the [Anno Domini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anno_Domini) origin of 0.

So my question is, what if I wanted to get the current `chrono::year`. Is there a function for that? I can obviously do:

```
const auto time = std::time(nullptr);
const auto current_date = *std::gmtime(&time);
const chrono::year foo{ current_date.tm_year + 1900 };
```

But that seems like a pretty convoluted process. Is there anything better available to me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
using namespace std::chrono;
year_month_day ymd = floor<days>(system_clock::now());
const year foo = ymd.year();
```

Comment: Wow, that's clever. I love the idea of being free from all the pointer passing involved in C's time library.

Comment: Fwiw, I've upvoted this answer.  But I also wanted to clarify that this is the current year **in UTC**.  If you want the current year in a specific time zone, that is doable using `chrono::zoned_time` (and will occasionally give you a different answer).  The code to do this is essentially a superset of the code presented in this answer.

Comment: What is the cast that allows `year_month_day ymd = floor<days>(system_clock::now())`? I'm not seeing the conversion between a `time_point` and `year_mont_day`.

Comment: `year_month_day` has an implicit `constexpr noexcept` constructor taking the single argument `const sys_days&`.  `sys_days` is just a type alias for `time_point<system_clock, days>`.  `floor<days>(...)` converts the `system_clock::time_point` to a `sys_days`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way:

```
auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
std::time_t now_c = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
struct tm *parts = std::localtime(&now_c);
std::cout << 1900 + parts->tm_year  << std::endl;
```